# Uncatchable Exception in Parallel.Invoke in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am having trouble catching exceptions thrown inside a `Parallel.Invoke` task from outside the same task.

On some PCs, such an exception will always cause the program to break into the debugger, even when everything is inside a `try catch` block.

On other PCs, such an exception will be wrapped inside an AggregateException, which can be caught on the main thread.

The following program runs fine on one PC, printing `"I don't care"` & `"whatever"`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
         throw new Exception("1");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I don't care");
    }


    try
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(
            new Action[]{
                ()=>{throw new Exception("2");},
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("whatever");
    }
}
```

But on another PC, visual studio always halts the program at the second exception (the first exception causes no problems)

[image]

My expectation would be that Parallel.Invoke swallows the `Exception("2")` and generates a new `AggregateException` on the main thread, that can be caught.

This seems to work on one PC, but not on another.

When I run the program without a debugger, everything runs fine.

Is there a particular Visual Studio setting that could cause this?

I checked whether there were any weird settings by clicking `Debugging/Exceptions/reset everything`, but without improvements:

[image]

Can anyone else reproduce this problem?

Comment: Exceptions settings, break on all exceptions thrown maybe?

Comment: I tried resetting everything under debugging/exceptions ( I have updated my question to add this). I could not see any difference. And both exceptions I throw are the same basic type: `new Exception()`, yet only the one inside `Parallel.Invoke` can sometimes not be caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this weird behaviour:

When the setting `just my code` is **enabled**, visual studio will **always break** on the exception inside the Parallel.Invoke, even if the resulting AggregateExpection is caught in user code

When that setting is **disabled**, visual studio will **not break** on the exception inside Parallel.Invoke. It will break on the resulting AggregateException only if that exception is not caught.

[image]

To prevent visual studio from breaking on the caught exception, *while keeping the setting `just my code` enabled*, you have to open `Debugging / Exceptions` and remove the check mark from

```
"Common language Runtime Exceptions / User-unhandled"
```

Caution: This is not the default setting, and when you click on `reset all`, this setting will be reverted.

Contrary to how it may sound like, after removing this check mark, visual studio will still break on unhandled exceptions, i.e. exceptions that are not inside any try-catch block.

[image]